# specify custom location of maven security-settings.xml file?

Tags: maven

with maven you can easily specify settings.xml location, e.g:

```
mvn -s custom/dir/settings.xml package
```

Is there a similiar way to specify custom security-settings.xml?

The reasoning behind this is simple: to easily distribute it via a local repository. Now, security is NOT a concern - it's all on the intranet.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

This was requested as [MNG-4853](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MNG-4853). Although not implemented directly, a workaround is suggested:

> I've verified that `-Dsettings.security=path/to/security-settings.xml` works

As detailed in [the announcement blog post](http://blog.sonatype.com/2009/02/new-feature-maven-settings-password-encryption/), you can also use the master password relocation feature. Write an `~/.m2/security-settings.xml` file with a redirection in it:

```
<settingsSecurity>
  <relocation>/Volumes/mySecureUsb/secret/settings-security.xml</relocation>
</settingsSecurity>
```

Comment: There is also [MNG-5438](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MNG-5438) with a patch for a command-line option.

Comment: mvn -ep REPOSITORY_PASSWORD -Dsettings.security=path/to/security-settings.xml