# how to find/create settings-security.xml file in Maven

Tags: macos, apache, maven

I am a mobile app developer & I am trying to setup Backbase CXP in my system. I have installed maven in my system manually & I can see .m2 folder in my system.

Now I am trying to set up password security but I could not found settings-security.xml file.

I have tried following links

[Link1](https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-encryption.html) 
[Link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23782409/specify-custom-location-of-maven-security-settings-xml-file) etc

Please let me how can I generate settings-security.xml file or let me know if I have to download from somewhere.

Comment: I think the frist link Show everything you have to know, what is the Problem with it?

Comment: This is a reasonable question.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look into the first link you have given:

> Store this password in the ${user.home}/.m2/settings-security.xml; it
>   should look like

The snippet after this you can use a template and fill in your details. That's it.